# Mockito: Try to mock a String returning method but giving null

Tags: java

I have a below method

```
public SizeDetails getsizeDetails(String Strength, String WPI)
```

So, I have used InjectsMock

```
@InjectMocks
ClassName mock;
```

Сreating object in setup() and using `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` and by that instance, I'm calling:

```
Mockito.when(mock.getWatermarksizeDetails(WATERMARKSTRENGTH, WATERMARKWPI, )).thenReturn(getSizeDetails());
```

But it is giving me null

`getSizeDetails()` has all the values.

Comment: Is your `getWatermarksizeDetails` being called with the correct parameters?

Comment: I am just using Mockito.anyString in parameter

Comment: whats the return value of getSizeDetails() during mocking?

Comment: SizeDetails is a pojo class and i am setting the some values in setter and returning the object. while debugging the cursor is going in the getSizeDetails() setting all the values but when it going in class which i am testing there it's returning null

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please enhance your code to a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You don't seem to be using `Mockito.anyString` in that code.

Comment: I tried with Mockito.anyString it was giving null so i hardcoded theconstant  values eg:"WATERMARKSTRENGTH" but still the same

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the mocked result from `getWatermarksizeDetails` you need to pass the same parameter values that you specified in the mocking sentence.

```
SizeDetails nonNullSizeDetails = className.getWatermarksizeDetails(
     WATERMARKSTRENGTH, WATERMARKWPI);
```

Or, you can change your `when` to use `Mockito.anyString()`

```
  Mockito.when(mock.getWatermarksizeDetails(Mockito.anyString(), 
    Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(getSizeDetails(WATERMARKSTRENGTH, WATERMARKWPI));
```